# Отличие ООП от процедурного стиля

Tags: php, ооп

этот вопрос больше направлен на теорию, но так же и затрагивает практику. В чем кардинальное различие ООП от процедурки?

Я не особо много видел кода ООП, но как по мне, для беглого чтения и понимания кода, ООП не может соревноваться с процедурным стилем.

Так почему же программисты выбирают именно ООП? Вот интересно, чем такой стиль написания кода подкупает, что люди переходят на него?

Comment: когда функционал больше чем вывод статей из базы, то ООП помагает избежать дублирования кода, и инкапсулировать функции в пространстве объекта.

Comment: процедурный подход как велосипед. ногами крутишь педали, руками - руль. видишь как вращаются колёса и цепь на звёздочке. ООП как автомобиль. не надо ладошками подливать бензин в цилиндры и толкать пятками поршни. оно само как-то под капотом работает. бегло устройство авто не прочитать конечно. зато можно бегло нажимая педаль домчаться дальше чем на велосипеде.

Comment: В ООП можно создавать свои типы. Это помогает. В принципе и на чистом Си можно писать ООП-программу, используя структуры как классы. Но просто на С++ (а это у нас сейчас типа главный язык по применению ООП) все это более явно выражено.

Comment: _ООП не может соревноваться с процедурным стилем._ - не может соревноваться в чем?

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос слишком личный - выберите любую задачу и попробуйте реализовать ее при помощи разных подходов. Тем самым вы решите для себя лично, что вам больше подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если пишет и поддерживает один человек - можно спорить, стоит ли применять процедурный стиль. Но Вы только попробуйте представить себе командное написание программного продукта в процедурном стиле!

Так что для меня кардинальное отличие: эффективное разделение кода на составляющие (классы), без которого командная работа сильно затруднена.